# Hosting web site with onion share

Tags: security, privacy

So, i don't use any kind of social media and i decided to make my web site instead of that. This idea is inspired by guy named Luke Smith from youtube and i want to make it to look smiliar to this: https://lukesmith.xyz/.

My plan is to host it with Onion share from home. So, my questions are:

1. This should be safe but how much is smart and safe to do this?
2. When i generate .onion link, who would have acces to it? It should be only people who got link from me? Am i right?
3. My hosting device and device of a person should not know about each other(IP adress). Is there any way to somehow one of us get more inforamtion then necessary?(IP adress)

Comment: Onion share looks like a tool for sending and receiving shared files, not a web sever.  https://docs.onionshare.org/2.3.3/en/features.html   Or am I missing something?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have a option to host a web server on Onion share applications.

Comment: Seems like it. The Tor system is designed to hide IP addresses, that's its whole point. Onion links are unguessable but anyone who knows the link can use it, however the link also gets sent to a small number of computers to manage the Tor network and they can see it without guessing. Looks like onionshare adds a password as well which does not have this problem.

Comment: @user253751 so it is safe to host it

Comment: @user253751 Thank you for help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure Onion Share only works over Tor, so anyone else wanting to visit your website would need a special Tor-enabled browser to view it. But maybe you already knew that!

Comment: @Maximillian Laumeister i know that. Thank you for responding!